# WAL segment has already been removed for logical replication

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12

I have setup logical replication (wal_level=logical) between Postgresql dbs (v12) with replication slot enabled. But I still get "WAL segment has already been removed" error:

```
ERROR:  requested WAL segment 00000001000002500000007C has already been removed
```

Then I have to delete this logical replication and create it again...

By my understanding, WAL won't be removed if replication slot enabled, right?

How could it happened? (High load on node, high replication latency, replication slot disbaled/deleted?)

Comment: Did you set `max_slot_wal_keep_size` on the primary? What is the `restart_lsn` in `pg_replication_slots`? What is your current `pg_current_wal_lsn()`?

Comment: Looks `max_slot_wal_keep_size` is introduced in pg v13, so I don't have it. I just deleted the existing slot for recoverying, so I can't tell you the `restart_lsn`... Could you please tell me how the `restart_lsn` and `pg_current_wal_lsn()` help me understand the situlation? I will check them when it happens next time. @LaurenzAlbe

Comment: Well, the difference tells you how much replication has fallen behind, which may be an interesting clue in connection with `max_slot_wal_keep_size` (which you don't have). `restart_lsn` is the place marked by the replication slot, so PostgreSQL should not delete any WAL that is more recent. It would be interesting to compare that with the WAL segment from the error message.

Comment: That shouldn't happen without max_slot_wal_keep_size.  Most likely, some person went in and mucked with pg_wal when they shouldn't have.  Although we can't rule out some kind of bug or (uncommanded) corruption.  And what minor release of 12 is this?

Comment: @jjanes PostgreSQL 12.5 (Debian 12.5-1.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit

Comment: The current release of that line is 12.14.  You are spurning 2 years worth of bug fixes.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Another error case happened: restart_lsn
16/5ED34848
pg_current_wal_lsn()
16/C55FAAC0